# Tree growth rings without seasons

Tags: day-night, sunlight, seasons

Tree growth rings are created because the time of day with sunlight differs throughout the year. How would the inside of a tree look, if it were to grow up on a planet without seasons, where day and night are always 1:1? I tried to look for studies on growing trees under artificial light, but couldn't find any.

Comment: Have you looked at how trees grow around the equator? There seasonal differences are minuscule.

Comment: @L.Dutch Good point, but aparently there are season's too. It does take away the sunlight, but not teampreature, humidity, etc.
[link](https://www.quora.com/Ecology-Do-trees-in-equatorial-countries-have-tree-rings-despite-the-lack-of-seasons)

Comment: @Raditz_35 real trees in unrealistic conditions. Think growing oak in an indoor greenhouse, where temperature, humidity, light and anything else is controlled.

Comment: I grew up in Hawaii, and I always wondered what were those tree rings everybody always talked about!  Seriously, though, while the trees may have rings, they're usually hardly noticable. But the thing I was told was that without the winter hardening, most of the wood grown here (all soft woods, I believe) are fine for building furniture, but not good for structural building.

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach it may be soft wood, but not softwood. Softwood means wood from conifers like pine or fir. Hardwood is Oak or Beech. A Hardwood like balsa is a soft wood. Whereas a softwood like yew can is a hard wood. Most trees in Hawaii are Hardwoods, but have soft wood. :-/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While it is true that tree growth rings are mainly due to seasonal differences in sun exposure they can also be caused by changes in humidity, temperature and rainfall patterns amongst other things.

Indeed in the tropics there are only tiny shifts in light levels year round and because of this many trees there tend not to have any visible growth rings at all. Yet because of the seasonal shifts that do in fact occur (namely changes in the rate of precipitation, a.k.a. wet season vs. dry season), some species of trees have subtle growth rings that reflect this. [Teak in particular is one tropical species that usually has very apparent rings.](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/21580103.2013.834275?utm_source=TrendMD&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Forest_Science_and_Technology_TrendMD_1&)

So essentially, if there are *absolutely no* seasonal changes to the environment of a tree, there won't be any growth rings. The cross section won't be completely homogenous however, they'll still be features such as the dead heartwood at the center of the log and the living sapwood which is typically lighter in color. On the other hand, if you do indeed have seasonal changes apart from illumination, then your tree may still have growth rings (though they'll tend to be less pronounced).

Answer (score 8):

**Tropical trees have rings.**

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/269621255_No_growth_stimulation_of_tropical_trees_by_150_years_of_CO2_fertilization_but_water-use_efficiency_increased

These researchers used the growth rings of tropical trees to study the possibility of growth stimulation by increasing CO2.

> The biomass of undisturbed tropical forests has likely increased in
>   the past few decades, probably as a result of accelerated tree
>   growth... However, there is no evidence that these physiological
>   responses do indeed stimulate tree growth in tropical forests. Here we
>   present measurements of stable carbon isotopes and growth rings in the
>   wood of 1,100 trees from Bolivia, Cameroon and Thailand.

[image: growth rings from tropical trees]

It is not stated why exactly they chose tropical trees - maybe because all other factors are more constant, or they could find really old trees more easily?  The image of tree rings is not the end-on sort of view I am used to but there they are.  There must be some cyclical change.  This might be intrinsic to the tree, not the environment - for example a tree might shift its resources to making seeds and fruit instead of wood at certain times of year.

---

If you want your alien tropical trees to have rings, have them cycle in some way as noted and that can do it.  Or have them be trees without rings - palm trees do not have rings.  Bamboo is a grass with tree ambitions and it does not have rings.

Comment: > There must be some cyclical change.   
Yes, even tropical areas generally have a wet and a dry season even if the amount of sunlight doesn't change, see for example the climate table of Manaus, a city in the middle of the largest rainforest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manaus#Climate

Answer (score 6):

> How would the inside of a tree look?

On Earth we have an example of a tree with no growth rings, even though it is not caused by seasonal changes.

The [palm tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecaceae) is such an example

[image: cross section of a palm tree]

As you can see from the picture above, there are no visible growth rings, so I guess it would look something like this.

Comment: Answers the question beautifully

Comment: I am afraid that a palm tree is not a good example. They are one of the few monocotyledons that are big enough to be considered a tree, and the rings are a characteristic of dicotyledons (other monocotyledons are bamboo, for example). Check "Vascular system" and "Difference with dicotyledons": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monocotyledon

Comment: @SJuan76, the OP asks "how would a tree look like without rings?". Palm tree is a tree, and has no rings.

Comment: Actually, palms are more closely related to grasses than other trees, and are not considered trees botanically. This is like using a koala bear to show that not all bears eat meat - the common name just isn't correct.

Comment: geez, pedantic much, you guys? There is no hard-super-technical-science tag on here. To most people, the above picture is of a "log" or a "cut tree" that has no visible rings to human eyes. While you are technically correct, unless you guys can provide an answer that shows a real "tree" with no rings, this is probably as close as the OP is going to get.

Comment: If I'm follwing correctly, the point is that palm trees, even if grown in an area with seasons, *still* would not have rings.

Answer (score -2):

If your planet has a moon, rings could be related to lunar cycles, or to tides.

If you want a longer cycle to affect your trees... The trees might have some biological trigger on them so that they only develop a ring if they get a short period of darkness between two long periods of light - that is, a solar eclipse.

On Earth those happen multiple times a year, but every time they happen on a different place. Once an eclipse happens over an area, it usually takes years for that to happen again. [A completely similar eclipse over a single area usually happens every 18 years](https://www.timeanddate.com/eclipse/how-often-solar-eclipse.html).

Comment: OP isn't saying they WANT rings without seasons and doesn't appear to be looking for ways to contrive them.